# Finding the cosine distance of a vector with multiple vectors in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the cosine distance of a vector with multiple vectors in a matrix.This is my matrix:

```
[[[ 0.04379608]
  [ 0.02680701]
  [ 0.33135787]]

 [[-0.07822198]
  [-0.12229042]
  [-0.14169733]]      

 [[ 0.06672882]
  [-0.05079487]
  [ 0.06437925]]

 [[ 0.04095123]
  [-0.16082226]
  [-0.04795549]]]
```

now I want to compare the first vectors cosine distance,

```
[[ 0.04379608]
 [ 0.02680701]
 [ 0.33135787]]
```

with other vectors. Similarly, I want to compare the second, third and fourth vector with each other by a for loop. This will produce five points.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged Python? Or are you looking for MATLAB only?

Comment: For Matlab, check [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) with the `'cosine'` option. That will avoid the need for a loop

Comment: Dear sir, I have edited my question. will you review it?